How to open a current Unreal buleprint in C++?
The main reason I want to open blueprints in C++ is because of an event Dispatcher. In the below image, there is an event dispatcher with the name "ButtonClicked2" i want to know what exactly happens when it is called. is there any way i can see it.(I double clicked it.Tried "Find Reference Option")

I double clicked it.Tried "Find Reference Option"

